# tabula-py table reading issue

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

[image: sample pdf table]

I am trying to read this pdf using `tabula-py` with all the default options. Which creates an issue. the first row of the second, third and fourth table is missing when I do so. To tackle that I started using `stream=True`, which creates another issue. the word `Location`, `Total` and `Elephant Road` are read as a single text block. So, I tried to read it as `lattice=True` which again misses the 2,3 and 4th table. Any suggestions or directions for me?

Comment: [source](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/chezou/tabula-py/blob/master/examples/tabula_example.ipynb#Read-partial-area-of-PDF) - try `area` to confine the table region and `columns` to fit the column coordinates

Comment: Will try it out. My source file must be the issue because it works fine sometimes and other times it doesn't.

Comment: i tried it did not work. tried setting the co ords to be relative and from 0,0 to 100,100 % same result.

Comment: See also: [How can I extract tables as structured data from PDF documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591426/562769)