# How can I extract tables from an image within a PDF / scanned PDF?

Tags: python, ocr, tabular, python-camelot

The job is to extract the table from the scanned PDF. I tried using Camelot/tabula, but nothing worked.

Any suggestions on how can I extract the tables?

### Example

[image]

Camelot/tabula none of them detects the table.
[image]

Attached the pdf link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1atUmkNBkOGYFn43ZQreNqSg74XRhFP61/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the problem when you tried to Camelot, can you give us a hint?

Comment: Camelot/tabula none of them recognize the table @SezaiBurakKantarcı

Comment: Without the original PDF, it is difficult to help you.
I add that, if the PDF is image-based (you can't select/copy text), neither Camelot nor Tabula work.

Comment: @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87, I have attached the original pdf. What's the other way to extract the table other than pytesseract. any suggestions?

Comment: Your issue is that this is a scanned drawing. If you have the originals, you should use those. If you only have the scanned image, you need to look into image-to-text libraries.

Comment: I recommend trying the Table Transformer: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/table-transformer

Comment: See also: [extract a table from a non-scanned PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591426/562769)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61431697/562769