# Convert the values in one single column to new multiple columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say, I have a data frame with a single column like this:

```
MRN: 5399394
    Adfdf Kim
    Telemedicine
      3/29/2021
    INT Pediatric Specialties - 
    G
    Encounter providers: 
    DB Polar, MD (Genetics) and Bar K Wright, 
    RD/LD (Nutrition)
    Primary diagnosis: 
    HUG
    Reason for Visit: 
    Referred by Provider Not In System
```

The output I am looking forward to is :

| MRN | Telemedicine | INT Pediatric Specialties | Encounter providers: | Primary diagnosis: | Reason for Visit: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5399394 | 3/29/2021 | G | DB Polar, MD (Genetics) and Bar K Wright, RD/LD (Nutrition) | HUG | Referred by Provider Not In System |
| Adfdf Kim |  |  |  |  |  |

I need to generate a new column with the strings ending with `:` or `-` or `\n` or `\s`

Comment: Telemedecine does not have a `:` or `-` char so why is it a column name ?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. The separators can be new line, space or full colon or hyphen

Comment: It poses another problem. How do you differentiate between a field name and a value ? A new column is generated with new lines and values are terminated with new lines as well.

Comment: That is the challenge here. I have extracted the provided column or input from a pdf. The pdf contains both text and tables. I used `PyPDF2` to extract the text, however, the text was all extracted as a single column in the CSV file. Therefore, I thought to modify the CSV as I wanted. If you have any suggestions to directly extract the table from the pdf would be great. So far I have used `pypdf2` and fitz or `pymuPDF` libraries. I have no JAVA license for `Tabula` at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried all the methods listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75419365/19593035) ?

Comment: Thanks, no I haven't. I can try those solutions.

Answer (score -1):

This question can be solved very easily by using pandas and numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = "MRN: 5399394 \n Adfdf Kim \n Telemedicine: \n 3/29/2021 \n INT Pediatric Specialties - \n G \n Encounter providers: \n DB Polar, MD (Genetics) and Bar K Wright, \n RD/LD (Nutrition) \n Primary diagnosis: \n HUG \n Reason for Visit: \n Referred by Provider Not In System"

x = data.split("\n")
x = [i.strip() for i in x]

d = {}

print(x)

flag = False
column = ""
multi_entry = False
add_all = False
count = 0
for i in x:
    for j in i:
        if j in [":", "-"]:
            flag = True
            if j == ":":
                colon = True
            else:
                colon = False

            if multi_entry:
                add_all = True
        if j == ",":
            multi_entry = True
            count += 1
            break

    if flag:
        if colon:
            temp = i.split(":")

        else:
            temp = i.split("-")

        d[temp[0].strip()] = []
        if temp[1] != '':
            d[temp[0].strip()].append(temp[1].strip())
        column = temp[0].strip()

        if add_all:
            current_index = x.index(i)

            d[list(d.keys())[-2]].append("\n ".join([x[index]
                                                     for index in range(current_index-1-count, current_index-1)]))
            multi_entry = False
            add_all = False

    else:
        if multi_entry:
            continue
        d[column].append(i)

    flag = False

# Determine the maximum length among all lists
max_length = max(len(v) for v in d.values())

# Pad the lists with NaN to make them the same length
for key, values in d.items():
    d[key] = values + [float('nan')] * (max_length - len(values))

# Create a DataFrame from the padded dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)
```

Since you didn't specify that your dataframe had multiple row entries or a single row entry as this, I assumed that the question had a single row. Either way, you could extract the entire data from the dataframe and come with a a list of entries. You could then split it up based on the column delimeters that you specified.

Hope this helps!