# Extracting data from PDFs into CSV

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I would like to extract all data into CSV, available from pages 4 to 605 from this [PDF](https://www.boe.es/boe/dias/2016/12/17/pdfs/BOE-A-2016-11948.pdf). Some people kindly suggest me to use `pypdf`.

I don't know how to use it. The structure of the PDF is complicated. Sometimes some columns are empty, others values are not homogeneized (e.g. in the column "VALOR", sometimes numbers can be written "1450", or "1.450", or "1 4   5  0", *etc.*

I hope you can help me! Thank you anyway for your help.

**P.S.:** I'm still very inexperienced in Python, so please excuse any errors in terminology and/or anything else.

Comment: You might be interested in the layout mode that pypdf will add soon-ish: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/discussions/2038#discussioncomment-7182826

Comment: Also a small heads-up: Extracting tables from PDF while maintaining the structure is a super hard problem. There is not a single solution that just works. There are some that might work in some cases, there might be better and worse solution.

Comment: @MartinThoma: Thank you for your feedback. You are right. Beforehand, I thought It would be an easy task. But indeed, it a cumbersome and hard to do it in a single shot.

Comment: Related: [How to extract a table as text from the PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47533875/562769) and [How can I extract tables as structured data from PDF documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591426/562769)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What you need ?

Indeed, [pypdf](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is good in extracting text from PDF, from documentation :

> pypdf is a free and open source pure-python PDF library capable of
> splitting, merging, cropping, and transforming the pages of PDF files.
> It can also add custom data, viewing options, and passwords to PDF
> files. pypdf can retrieve text and metadata from PDFs as well.

But in your case, [tabula](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#example)  is what you need  :

> tabula-py enables you to extract tables from a PDF into a DataFrame,
> or a JSON. It can also extract tables from a PDF and save the file as
> a CSV, a TSV, or a JSON.

### Installation :

You can install `tabula` using `pip`:

```
pip install tabula-py
```

For faster execution install it with  `jpype`:

```bash
pip install tabula-py[jpype]
```

### How to use `tabula.read_pdf` :

`tabula.read_pdf`  is the function we gonna use to extract tables from the PDF file. We are interested in the following Parameters :

- **input_path** : The input file
- **pages** pages: Extract from ("4-605" extract all table form 4 to 605)
- **pandas_options**: Set pandas options
- **area** : To be more efficient we need to specify the area where the table is in the pages in format (top,left,bottom,right)
- **columns** : list of  X coordinates of column boundaries.

Let do some measurement !!

### Measurement, The fun part!

The picture is screenshot of page 5 of the [PDF](https://www.boe.es/boe/dias/2016/12/17/pdfs/BOE-A-2016-11948.pdf), all other pages are similar to this page (except page 4).

What we are interested in is the green area that contain the rows we need, in this case

```
area=[145, 70, 777, 525]
```

For page 4 the top is different:

```
area_p4=[250, 70, 777, 525]
```

[image]

We need also the X coordinates of column boundaries to avoid misplacement of columns values :

```
X=[120, 315, 365, 383, 405, 419, 444, 464, 485, 500, 530]
```

##### Note :  the red region should be part of the green area , but `tabula` encounters difficulty managing it as multi-line column names are treated as separate rows.

We can set names using pandas options :

```py
column_names = [
    "MARCA", "MODELO -TIPO", "PERIODOCOMERCIAL",
    "C.C.", "Nº de cilind.", "G/D", "P kW", "cvf",
    "CO2 g/km", "cv", "2017 VALOR Euros"
]

pandas_options = {
    "header": 0,
    "names":column_names
}
```

You can name columns in better way !

### Coding , The easy part !

Most of the work is done , what we need is extract tables for the PDF:

```py
with open("file.pdf", 'rb') as file:
        # extract table from pages
        dfs = read_pdf(
            file,
            pages="5-605", # pages to extract table from
            area=area,
            columns=X,
            pandas_options=pandas_options,
        )

        # extract table in page 4
        df_4 = read_pdf(
              file,
              pages=4,
              area=area_p4, 
              columns=X,
              pandas_options=pandas_options,
        )
```

Then , we need to concatenate all dfs into one DataFrame using [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
# add page 4 table to the other tables
dfs.extend(df_4)

# concat all dfs to get one table
data = pd.concat(
    dfs,
    axis=0,
    ignore_index=True
)
```

Now , we can check some sample output  :

```
data.sample(5)
```

| index | MARCA | MODELO -TIPO | PERIODOCOMERCIAL | C.C. | Nº de cilind. | G/D | P kW | cvf | CO2 g/km | cv | 2017 VALOR Euros |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 193 | ALFA ROMEO | ALFA 159 1.9 JTD ti 150 | 2008-2012 | 1910.0 | 4.0 | D | 110 | 12,96 | 157.0 | 150.0 | 27300.0 |
| 172 | ALFA ROMEO | ALFA 159 1.9 JTS Selective | 2008-2012 | 1859.0 | 4.0 | G | 118 | 12,75 | 205.0 | 161.0 | 24300.0 |
| 200 | ALFA ROMEO | ALFA 159 2.0 JTDM Elegante ECO | 2008-2012 | 1956.0 | 4.0 | D | 125 | 13,14 | 136.0 | 170.0 | 24000.0 |
| 164 | ALFA ROMEO | ALFA 156 Sportwagon 2.5 V6 Distinctive Q-System | 2003-2006 | 2492.0 | 6.0 | G | 141 | 17,88 | NaN | 192.0 | 25100.0 |
| 102 | ALFA ROMEO | ALFA 156 1.6 TS | 1997-2002 | 1598.0 | 4.0 | G | 88 | 11,64 | NaN | 120.0 | 13500.0 |

Finally, You can find full code in this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oZmZtgP5MO2BLTc2XERzpQFDKUkb57en?usp=sharing)

### Edit :

[Tabula](https://tabula.technology/) a webapp friendly tools designed to run locally on your machine.

You can select tables manually or automatically, the have feature to Autodetect tables using [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) :

> Next, we detect the boundaries of the table rows. If the table
> contains ruling lines to separate rows, we use their position to
> generate the boundaries (top and bottom) of each row. The lines are
> detected with a computer vision technique called Hough transform, as
> implemented in the OpenCV library.

You can use it to extract the data , or get the areas of table :

[image]

You can export the template as json , here is the output for page 4 :

```json
[{"page":4,"extraction_method":"guess","x1":75.15359512329101,"x2":522.3546908569336,"y1":250.3879679107666,"y2":782.4158937835693,"width":447.2010957336426,"height":532.0279258728027}]
```

Comment: Hi @Hamza! Thank you very much for your answer and explanations!

I will have a try! Thanks for the Colab Notebook! Really nice from you!
Lovely day!

Perhaps one more question, please: what is the unit of measure that used (px)?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: And perhaps one more question, please. Some lines are strangely coded. For example, this one:

:A BLFOAE R-OAM-2E0O16-1,A1L9F4A8 156 2.0 JTS Selespeed,2002-2003,1970.0,4,G,121,"13,20",,165,19800

Could you have a suggestion to correct that please? Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I also see that some initial letters are cut off (for example: "UDI", "OLKSWAGEN", etc. ). This only occurs from page 514 up to 605. Probably the area changes.

Comment: px is [pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel) , But tabula use [Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography))  where `1pt = 1/72inch` . I updated the image

Comment: the page 514 is different so it may need to customize  the `area` parameter like we did with page 4

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. So the x coordinates are given in pts, or pixels? The pattern of page 514 goes up to the end, if I am not mistaken. So basically, what I need to do is customize the area from 514 onwards, right? Thank you so much! Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: The x coordinates is on pt (I was luck to have 1px=1pt not always the case)

Comment: I updated the answer to add [tabula webapp](https://tabula.technology/).

Comment: Finally, Could you accept the answer ! Thank you

Comment: Perfect, all is clear now! Thank you Hamza. Great work!

Comment: Welcome, Enjoy your day